# MySQL upgrade from 5.0 to 5.5

Tags: mysql, upgrade

I would like to upgrade MySQL from version 5.0 (I have 5.0.86) to 5.5 (let's say 5.5.17)

After some search, i found this method :

1. Dump the databases but not mysql databse in a backup_data.sql
2. This is the most important step: dump mysql database with the
   option `--complete-insert` and `--no-create-info` in a file (lets say
   mysql.sql) : the idea is to obtain an sql database as similar as if
   setup a 5.5 version from scratch and create users after.
3. Uninstall 5.0 - install 5.5
4. Recover mysql database and flush the privilege to restore it.
5. Recover the other databases.

My problem happen in step 4 : when i do :

```
mysql -u root mysql < mysql.sql
```

I got error about duplicate entry for key primary. When i dump mysql database without the options `--complete-insert` and `--no-create-info`, the recover works fine BUT i obtain an sql database different from if i created it with a new 5.5 setup and that's not i want.

Any idea about this problem or any suggestions ?

Comment: The official reference you needed here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/upgrading.html

Answer (score 1):

You cannot mysqldump the mysql schema and simply import to the higher version. Why ? In the DBA StackExchange, I answered this question a little over a year ago: [**Cannot GRANT privileges as root**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/16397/877). In short, the table `mysql.user` has a different number of columns for each major release of MySQL:

- 43 columns in MySQL 5.6
- 42 columns in MySQL 5.5
- 39 columns in MySQL 5.1
- 37 columns in MySQL 5.0
- 31 columns in MySQL 4.x
- [**See my answer to see the columns**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/16441/877)

What you can do is dump `mysql.user` using one of two techniques:

## TECHNIQUE #1

Use one of the following Percona Tools

- [**pt-show-grants**](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-show-grants.html)
- [**mk-show-grants**](http://www.maatkit.org/doc/mk-show-grants.html)

Echo the output of either program to a text file.

## TECHNIQUE #2

You can emulate [**pt-show-grants**](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-show-grants.html) as follows:

```
cd
MYSQL_CONN="-uroot -ppassword"
SQLSTMT="SELECT CONCAT('SHOW GRANTS FOR ',"
SQLSTMT="${SQLSTMT} QUOTE(user),'@',QUOTE(host),';') "
SQLSTMT="${SQLSTMT} FROM mysql.user WHERE user<>''"
mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} -ANe"${SQLSTMT}" > GetGrants.sql
echo "SET sql_log_bin = 0;" > MySQLUserGrants.sql
mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} -AN < GetGrants.sql | sed 's/$/;/g' >> MySQLUserGrants.sql
rm -f GetGrants.sql
```

That is the cleanest and safest way to migrate grants from version to version. I have successfully upgraded MySQL 5.0 to MySQL 5.1/5.5 many times. You cannot go MySQL 5.0 to MySQL 5.6 because IMHO the 16-character [**PASSWORD()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_password) function hash is not available via old_password. If you have the plain text passwords for all users, simply edit MySQLUserGrants.sql replacing `IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '16-char hash'` with `IDENTIFIED BY 'plaintext password'`. Then you can execute it in MySQL 5.6. When done, quickly delete MySQLUserGrants.sql.

Answer (score 0):

Backup the mysql.* database. Re-export your mysql database with the `--replace` flag and re-import. If that doesn't have the intended effect, [check out the scripts on this post for dumping grants.](https://serverfault.com/questions/338419/mysql-upgrade-from-5-0-to-5-5)